# Checking surrounding coordinates in a grid and changing the current coordinate properties accordingly

Tags: java, android, grid

I'm making a grid-based game where you have land and water and the land tiles should change their image depending on how tiles around it are also land tiles. What would be the most efficient way to go about this?
for example, if it looked liked this on the grid( the O being the current position)

L L L

L O L

W W W

the tile would be a southern coastline image

Comment: Most efficient speed wise? Most efficient code / time wise :)? See http://www.andengine.org/. They have already implemented a tile based engine for gaming.

Comment: Can't use engine, this is for a school project. everything must be coded from scratch.

Comment: a little of both, since I'm on android I have limited resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there's only two cases: land or water, then there are 2^8 = 256 possibilities.  So simplest might be do a table lookup.  The table would have an index of one of the possible land images.  The case above might be **table[b11111000]**

Comment: That would work. I don't check diagonally though, so far fewer possibilities. Thanks